# proof on equality of sets

Tags: proof-writing

If i want to Prove $A^c \cup B^c$ = $(A \cap B)^c$ by a string of equalities

=$\{x|x\in A^c \cup B^c\}$

=$\{x|x\in A^c orx\in B^c\}$

=$\{x|x\notin A orx\notin B\}$

=$\{x|x\notin (A \cap B)\}$

=$\{x|x\in (A \cap B)^c\}$

1/ Is this proof ok as it stands?

2/ if i wanted to justify line 4 would suppose $x\in (A \cap B)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ which contradicts line 3 be ok.

3/ as this i s a string of equalities would it be ok to put that argument beside line 4?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add a line in between to better show the logic ... and that will also make your question about the justification more clear:

... =$\{x|x\notin A \text{ or } x\notin B\}$

$\color{red}{=\{x|\text{ it is not the case that } x\in A \text{ and } x\in B\}}$

=$\{x|x\notin (A \cap B)\}$

=$\{x|x\in (A \cap B)^c\}$

The logical justification of going from

$\{x|x\notin A \text{ or } x\notin B\}$

to

$\{x|\text{ it is not the case that } x\in A \text{ and } x\in B\}$

is by logical DeMorgan:  in abstract terms, you have a statement of the form $\neg p \lor \neg q$, which is equivalent to $\neg (p \land q)$